# OEIS database download

Tags: sequences-and-series, oeis

I am interested in downloading the first 25 integers of each sequence in the OEIS database. My reason for wanting to do so is to find the arithmetic mean of the first integers, the arithmetic mean of the second integers, etc. and then plot these values.  The hope is that there is a relatively smooth curve that emerges for the mean values even though many of these sequences are wildly chaotic.  Similarly I want to find the median, standard deviations, geometric mean and other statistics on these integers. In fact by rounding these values to integers, it would define a new sequence, call it the "OEIS mean 2018 sequence" and so forth. Over time the OEIS sequence would change as more sequences are added to the database, hence the date stamp.

When I visit the site, I can only download one sequence at a time, which would be way too much effort for all 250,000 (+) sequences.  Is there a way to query the entire database at once?

Comment: I suggest you to try to find any evidence that "there is a relatively smooth curve" before trying this empirical approach. You know, "extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence".

Comment: Do you mean this page: https://oeis.org/A000001 ?

Comment: Have you tried contacting Sloane?

Comment: I might give that a try.  I was hoping there was an obvious answer before I tried that. Thanks.

Comment: Software-wise, downloading using something like wget with a generated list of all 360,000 urls would take about 4 months run 24/7 at "polite" speeds.  I would second contacting the president of OEIS (info is on the main page) or maybe sending an email to webmaster(at)oeis.org.  If you're polite, the webmaster might be able to query a database and get you the exact info you need.

Comment: https://oeis.org/stripped.gz

Comment: Research like yours can be interesting so I wish you luck. There are already some surprising (funny?) results coming from bulk analysis of integer sequencies. Check this excellent Numberphile video, some numbers are definitely ugly: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_YysNM2JoFo

Comment: The entire OEIS data is now available at https://github.com/oeis/oeisdata

Answer (score 14):

Yes, you can download [the sequences and their A-numbers](https://oeis.org/wiki/Welcome#Compressed_Versions) in a gzipped file that's updated daily.

Comment: You just saved me a lot of scraping!